# Windows 10 BSOD - Probably caused by : win32kbase.sys ( win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived+254 )

Tags: windows, memory, bsod

I bought a Lenovo 700-15ISK. Several times I received a BSOD.
I checked the RAM Memtest and all ok. I installed the drivers from the Lenovo (dedicated to my model), except for Intel Management Engine Interface, Intel Serial I/O because I had newer.

Below the content DMP with last accident.

Does anybody know how to solve this problem?

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.14321.1024 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Users\elcol\Desktop\010217-12906-01.dmp]
Mini Kernel Dump File: Only registers and stack trace are available

Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 14393 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
Built by: 14393.576.amd64fre.rs1_release_inmarket.161208-2252
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff801`77609000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff801`7790e060
Debug session time: Mon Jan  2 20:39:13.407 2017 (UTC + 1:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:08:43.176
Loading Kernel Symbols
.

Press ctrl-c (cdb, kd, ntsd) or ctrl-break (windbg) to abort symbol loads that take too long.
Run !sym noisy before .reload to track down problems loading symbols.

..............................................................
................................................................
...............................................................
Loading User Symbols
Loading unloaded module list
.......
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck C4, {f5, 0, ffffa3801ccc4c60, 0}

Probably caused by : win32kbase.sys ( win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived+254 )

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------

5: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_VERIFIER_DETECTED_VIOLATION (c4)
A device driver attempting to corrupt the system has been caught.  This is
because the driver was specified in the registry as being suspect (by the
administrator) and the kernel has enabled substantial checking of this driver.
If the driver attempts to corrupt the system, bugchecks 0xC4, 0xC1 and 0xA will
be among the most commonly seen crashes.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000000000f5, ObReferenceObjectByHandle is being called with a NULL handle.
Arg2: 0000000000000000, Handle value specified by the caller.
Arg3: ffffa3801ccc4c60, Object type specified by the caller.
Arg4: 0000000000000000

Debugging Details:
------------------


DUMP_CLASS: 1

DUMP_QUALIFIER: 400

BUILD_VERSION_STRING:  10.0.14393.576 (rs1_release_inmarket.161208-2252)

SYSTEM_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

SYSTEM_PRODUCT_NAME:  80RU

SYSTEM_SKU:  LENOVO_MT_80RU_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo ideapad 700-15ISK

SYSTEM_VERSION:  Lenovo ideapad 700-15ISK

BIOS_VENDOR:  LENOVO

BIOS_VERSION:  E5CN56WW

BIOS_DATE:  09/29/2016

BASEBOARD_MANUFACTURER:  LENOVO

BASEBOARD_PRODUCT:  Lenovo ideapad 700-15ISK

BASEBOARD_VERSION:  NO DPK

DUMP_TYPE:  2

BUGCHECK_P1: f5

BUGCHECK_P2: 0

BUGCHECK_P3: ffffa3801ccc4c60

BUGCHECK_P4: 0

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xc4_f5

CPU_COUNT: 8

CPU_MHZ: a20

CPU_VENDOR:  GenuineIntel

CPU_FAMILY: 6

CPU_MODEL: 5e

CPU_STEPPING: 3

CPU_MICROCODE: 6,5e,3,0 (F,M,S,R)  SIG: 74'00000000 (cache) 74'00000000 (init)

CUSTOMER_CRASH_COUNT:  1

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VERIFIER_ENABLED_VISTA_MINIDUMP

PROCESS_NAME:  csrss.exe

CURRENT_IRQL:  0

ANALYSIS_SESSION_HOST:  DESKTOP-HKKCHJ7

ANALYSIS_SESSION_TIME:  01-02-2017 21:02:06.0384

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 10.0.14321.1024 amd64fre

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80177d15360 to fffff801777536f0

STACK_TEXT:  
ffffc780`472dc6c8 fffff801`77d15360 : 00000000`000000c4 00000000`000000f5 00000000`00000000 ffffa380`1ccc4c60 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffc780`472dc6d0 fffff801`77d25da9 : 00000000`00000000 ffffc780`472dc7d9 ffffa380`1ccc4c60 00000000`00000000 : nt!VerifierBugCheckIfAppropriate+0x48
ffffc780`472dc710 fffffb20`3edbabc4 : 00000000`00000000 ffffc780`472dc7d9 ffffa380`23750570 00000000`00000000 : nt!VerifierObReferenceObjectByHandle+0xb9
ffffc780`472dc750 fffffb20`3ee17a34 : 00000000`00000000 ffffc780`472dc9a9 ffffc780`472dc998 ffffa380`232f41f0 : win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived+0x254
ffffc780`472dc840 fffffb20`3ea21052 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : win32kbase!RIMAddNonPnpDeviceOfTypeUsingSuppliedFileHandle+0x124
ffffc780`472dc8f0 fffffb20`3ed9cb7c : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00269fb3 ffffa380`00000001 00000000`00000002 : win32kfull!xxxDesktopThread+0x6c2
ffffc780`472dca10 fffffb20`3ea9372f : 00000000`00000001 fffffb20`3eeb09a0 00000000`00000004 00000000`00000000 : win32kbase!xxxCreateSystemThreads+0x6c
ffffc780`472dca50 fffff801`7775e393 : ffffa380`23f11080 00000000`00000004 00000267`99d0a5f8 00000267`99d04f20 : win32kfull!NtUserCallNoParam+0x2f
ffffc780`472dca80 00007ff8`a1f71144 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd+0x13
000000fd`61b3f7a8 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff8`a1f71144


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC:  a3fb7771e6a1795db836fabaa3d2e2570ff88095

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD_FUNC_OFFSET:  80c49bbda5d71235d87911337d4f82fb3aa2110c

THREAD_SHA1_HASH_MOD:  0745d0c298af4320efd071415d32a539ba294c1f

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived+254
fffffb20`3edbabc4 448bf0          mov     r14d,eax

FAULT_INSTR_CODE:  48f08b44

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived+254

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: win32kbase

IMAGE_NAME:  win32kbase.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  584a777e

IMAGE_VERSION:  10.0.14393.576

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  254

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0xc4_f5_VRF_win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived

BUCKET_ID:  0xc4_f5_VRF_win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  0xc4_f5_VRF_win32kbase!rimOnPnpArrived

TARGET_TIME:  2017-01-02T19:39:13.000Z

OSBUILD:  14393

OSSERVICEPACK:  576

SERVICEPACK_NUMBER: 0

OS_REVISION: 0

SUITE_MASK:  272

PRODUCT_TYPE:  1

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

OSEDITION:  Windows 10 WinNt TerminalServer SingleUserTS

OS_LOCALE:  

USER_LCID:  0

OSBUILD_TIMESTAMP:  2016-12-09 10:23:02

BUILDDATESTAMP_STR:  161208-2252

BUILDLAB_STR:  rs1_release_inmarket

BUILDOSVER_STR:  10.0.14393.576

ANALYSIS_SESSION_ELAPSED_TIME: 4bf

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  KM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  km:0xc4_f5_vrf_win32kbase!rimonpnparrived

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {ee1f2564-23a0-fe46-4311-33b049cbda1f}

Followup:     MachineOwner
---------
```

Comment: disable driververifier to have a more stable system and update all GPU related drivers.

Comment: Did not help... https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B53VnnaeEGQIVjBPeGs4cTFlcVk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: any update on this issue?

Comment: Having the same issue on a Lenovo T460s laptop, after the newest Windows creators update (build 16299)

Answer (score 2):

I checked the dumps and 2 show memory corruptions:

```
STACK_TEXT:  
ffff9001`701eb6b8 fffff800`bd610cad : 00000000`0000001a 00000000`00005003 ffffbb80`10804310 00000000`000040da : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffff9001`701eb6c0 fffff800`bd525e32 : 00000000`00000007 ffff9001`701eb800 ffff9001`701eb820 7fffffff`ffffffff : nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x3b11d
ffff9001`701eb720 fffff800`bd52446a : ffffffff`00000480 00000000`00000004 ffffbd0b`45b0f980 ffff9001`701eb980 : nt!MiDispatchFault+0x902
ffff9001`701eb880 fffff800`bd5cfcfc : ffffbd0b`45bc0080 00000000`00000000 ffffbd0b`46d23ab0 ffffbd0b`46d23ab0 : nt!MmAccessFault+0x67a
ffff9001`701eba80 00007ff7`2fd6dff3 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x13c
00000056`26cfdcf0 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : 0x00007ff7`2fd6dff3


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff800bd610cbd - nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+3b12d
    [ f6:a5 ]
1 error : !nt (fffff800bd610cbd)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  ONE_BYTE

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BYTE

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BYTE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_ONE_BYTE


STACK_TEXT:  
ffffad80`cd7cee08 fffff800`eb061a6e : 00000000`000000c1 ffffaa00`a6d02d90 ffffaa00`a6d02b44 00000000`00b94270 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
ffffad80`cd7cee10 fffff800`eb0626a2 : 00000000`00000004 fffff800`eaeb5383 ffffaa00`a6d02000 00000000`00000270 : nt!MiCheckSpecialPoolSlop+0x8a
ffffad80`cd7cee50 fffff800`eb0c6c77 : ffffaa00`a6d02d90 ffffffff`ffffbe30 00000000`00000000 00000000`6e706657 : nt!MmFreeSpecialPool+0x166
ffffad80`cd7cefb0 fffff803`fa318de0 : ffffaa00`a6d02d90 00000168`00000000 00470080`00000000 00000000`1e5492fc : nt!ExDeferredFreePool+0x4d7
ffffad80`cd7cf090 fffff800`eb57b464 : ffffaa00`a6d02d90 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000001 ffffaa00`a6d02e00 : VerifierExt!ExFreePoolWithTag_wrapper+0x10
ffffad80`cd7cf0c0 fffff803`fae100ad : ffffaa00`7846ef80 fffff803`fdb5298f 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000004f : nt!VerifierExFreePoolWithTag+0x44
ffffad80`cd7cf0f0 fffff803`fae0f7ec : ffffaa00`a6d02d90 fffff800`eb595ea7 00000000`00000001 ffffd50f`5342ee48 : NETIO!PplGenericFreeFunction+0x4d
ffffad80`cd7cf120 fffff803`fb13119f : ffffaa00`a6d02d90 00000000`00000000 ffffad80`cd7cf1d9 ffffbfdf`eff54010 : NETIO!WfpNblInfoDestroyIfUnused+0xec
ffffad80`cd7cf160 fffff803`fae1023f : ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000000 ffffaa00`7825e700 00000000`00000000 : fwpkclnt!FwppNetBufferListEventNotify+0x19f
ffffad80`cd7cf240 fffff803`fbac6dd1 : ffffaa00`aec14e90 ffffad80`cd7cf2c0 ffffaa00`9e01c680 fffff803`ffacc700 : NETIO!WfpNblInfoCleanup+0x4f
ffffad80`cd7cf280 fffff803`fbea1a39 : ffffaa00`9e0f4ca0 ffffaa00`bd420e70 ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000000 : ndis!NdisFreeCloneNetBufferList+0x1f1
ffffad80`cd7cf330 fffff803`fbae8f8b : fffff803`fbea1940 fffff803`fbade650 00000000`00000000 ffffad80`cd7cf520 : vwififlt!FilterSendNetBufferListsComplete+0xf9
ffffad80`cd7cf390 fffff803`fbade68e : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisCallSendCompleteHandler+0x26d5b
ffffad80`cd7cf3d0 fffff800`eaf07505 : ffffad80`cd7cf539 ffffad80`cd7cf520 00000000`00000000 fffff800`eb19bd00 : ndis!ndisDataPathExpandStackCallback+0x3e
ffffad80`cd7cf420 fffff803`fbad2a75 : ffffaa00`aec14e90 ffffaa00`9e0dcc70 ffffaa00`9e086c70 ffffaa00`aec14e90 : nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutInternal+0x85
ffffad80`cd7cf470 fffff803`fbad0539 : ffffaa00`aec14e90 fffff800`eae97680 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisExpandStack+0x19
ffffad80`cd7cf4b0 fffff803`fbaefdb2 : ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000000 ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisInvokeNextSendCompleteHandler+0x131
ffffad80`cd7cf590 fffff803`fbb23bd8 : ffffaa00`aec14e90 ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : ndis!NdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete+0x225f2
ffffad80`cd7cf610 fffff803`fb1a1696 : ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000000 ffff7ab2`84a1b870 00000000`00000000 : ndis!ndisVerifierNdisFSendNetBufferListsComplete+0x28
ffffad80`cd7cf650 fffff803`fbae8f08 : 00000000`00000000 ffffaa00`aec14e90 ffffd50f`563c7000 ffffaa00`aec14e90 : wfplwfs!LwfLowerSendNetBufferListsComplete+0xb6
ffffad80`cd7cf6a0 fffff803`fbb23c68 : ffffd50f`562661a0 ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000000 ffffaa00`aec14e02 : ndis!NdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete+0x26fa8
ffffad80`cd7cf790 fffff803`fea4ca17 : ffffaa00`8034ed90 00000000`00000000 ffffad80`cd7cf828 fffff800`eaf0accc : ndis!ndisVerifierNdisMSendNetBufferListsComplete+0x28
ffffad80`cd7cf7d0 fffff803`fea1ff03 : ffffaa00`8034ed90 00000000`00000001 ffffaa00`aec14e90 00000000`00000000 : wdiwifi!CPort::SendCompleteNetBufferLists+0xef
ffffad80`cd7cf820 fffff803`fea15e11 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 ffffaa00`aec14e90 ffffd50f`563ca790 : wdiwifi!CAdapter::SendCompleteNbl+0x123
ffffad80`cd7cf890 fffff803`fea1321e : 00000000`00000001 ffffd50f`563ca848 00000000`0000ffff 00000000`00000000 : wdiwifi!CTxMgr::CompleteNdisNbl+0xbd
ffffad80`cd7cf8f0 fffff803`ff2f27d2 : ffffd50f`563c7000 00000000`00000000 ffffd50f`565c0601 fffff803`ff3fe000 : wdiwifi!CTxMgr::TxTransferCompleteInd+0x5be
ffffad80`cd7cf9a0 ffffd50f`563c7000 : 00000000`00000000 ffffd50f`565c0601 fffff803`ff3fe000 ffffaa00`7f452b50 : Netwtw04+0x227d2
ffffad80`cd7cf9a8 00000000`00000000 : ffffd50f`565c0601 fffff803`ff3fe000 ffffaa00`7f452b50 00000000`00000001 : 0xffffd50f`563c7000


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

CHKIMG_EXTENSION: !chkimg -lo 50 -d !nt
    fffff800eb0c6c85-fffff800eb0c6c87  3 bytes - nt!ExDeferredFreePool+4e5
    [ 40 fb f6:c0 df bf ]
    fffff800eb0c6cb9-fffff800eb0c6cba  2 bytes - nt!ExDeferredFreePool+519 (+0x34)
    [ 80 fa:00 a2 ]
5 errors : !nt (fffff800eb0c6c85-fffff800eb0c6cba)

MODULE_NAME: memory_corruption

IMAGE_NAME:  memory_corruption

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  memory_corruption

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  0

MEMORY_CORRUPTOR:  LARGE

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

BUCKET_ID:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  MEMORY_CORRUPTION_LARGE
```

And in 2 dumps I see a crashes related to NTFS/Cache operations:

```
00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt!KiBugCheckDispatch
02 nt!KiPageFault
03 nt!CcFindNextWorkQueueEntry
04 nt!CcWorkerThread
05 nt!ExpWorkerThread
06 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup
07 nt!KiStartSystemThread

00 nt!KeBugCheckEx
01 nt! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'
02 nt!MmAccessFault
03 nt!KiPageFault
04 nt!FsRtlAcquireHeaderMutex
05 NTFS!NtfsCleanupIrpContext
06 NTFS!NtfsExtendedCompleteRequestInternal
07 NTFS!NtfsCommonCreate
08 NTFS!NtfsCommonCreateCallout
09 nt!KxSwitchKernelStackCallout
0a nt!KiSwitchKernelStackContinue
0b nt!KiExpandKernelStackAndCalloutOnStackSegment
0c nt!KiExpandKernelStackAndCalloutSwitchStack
0d nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutInternal
0e NTFS!NtfsFsdCreate
0f FLTMGR!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted
10 FLTMGR!FltpCreate
11 nt!IopParseDevice
12 nt!ObpLookupObjectName
13 nt!ObOpenObjectByNameEx
14 nt!IopCreateFile
15 nt!NtCreateFile
16 nt!KiSystemServiceCopyEnd
```

So it could be disk issues, that some Windows files are damaged on the HDD, or get damaged in RAM because of RAM issues.

So run a memtest, check the HDD for errors, run `chkdsk C: /F` to detect and repair NTFS issues and [run DISM](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/joscon/2012/09/26/fixing-component-store-corruption-in-windows-8-and-windows-server-2012/) to check if all windows files are ok.

If nothings helps, RMA the device if it is relatively and you still have warranty.